# Could you recommend a book for studying calculus 1?

Tags: calculus, textbooks, exercises

I would like to practice a large quantity of exercises from limit calculation, derivatives, sequences and series and finaly integrals.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Please say more about your background and purpose. Why are you studying it? What’s the end goal?

Comment: Studying for college exam, im in mechanical engineering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend [OpenStax](https://openstax.org/subjects/math) open-resource digital books from Rice University for all levels of college math, from prealgebra through calculus and statistics. For the student, they're free, can be shared and copied without restriction, carried on mobile devices, etc. From the instructor's perspective, one can rely on immediate access by all students, show the content on overhead projectors, remix the content into presentations and handouts, etc. In my opinion they're at the same level as any professional print text, after several years of development, and boast extensive lists of professorial authors, editors, and reviewers (e.g. *Calculus* primary author Gilbert Strang is from MIT).

Calculus comes in three volumes:

- [OpenStax Calculus Volume 1](https://openstax.org/details/books/calculus-volume-1)
- [OpenStax Calculus Volume 2](https://openstax.org/details/books/calculus-volume-2)
- [OpenStax Calculus Volume 3](https://openstax.org/details/books/calculus-volume-3)

Answer (score 0):

A.  Granville is a good source of classic problems.  Free copy on web:

http://djm.cc/library/Elements_Differential_Integral_Calculus_Granville_edited_2.pdf

Don't be put off by the age.  It is the first modern text.  Almost all the problems have answers in back.  It was actually designed to have double the problems needed (so that instructors could assign a "full" suite for at home work or a full suite for in class).

B. Also there are some popular drill books (10-25 bucks for bound copy) available at Amazon or book stores. I would recommend a hard copy as I hear bad things about digitized math books for legibility.

1. Schaum's 3000 Solved Problems
2. Schaum's Outline of Calculus by Frank Ayres (earlier used editions preferred but all OK).
3. The Humongous Book of Calculus Problems

C.  Also check out Khan Academy for free drill problems online.

D.  This is a bit more obscure but I am a fan of Thomas Finney
Elements of Calculus and Analytic Geometry 4th Edition:

[https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Calculus-Analytic-Geometry-George/dp/0201076640](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201076640) (used copies for under $10)

You may recognize the cover from the movie Stand and Deliver (I used it in HS also).  Escalante said nice things about its problems as well in a research article.  Note that it has ALL the answers in the back, ideal for the self-learner.

Answer (score 0):

[Calculus Problems](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783319154275) by Baronti, De Mari, van der Putten & Venturi might be worth a look. It has problems on all the topics you mention, along with basic ordinary differential equations. There is also a final chapter containing problems whose solution may require techniques from throughout the book.